# fread returns no data in my buffer in spite of saying it read 4096 bytes

Tags: c, macos, fread

I'm porting some C code that loads sprites from files containing multiple bitmaps. Basically the code fopens the file, fgetcs some header info, then freads the bitmap data. I can see that the fgetcs are returning proper data, but the outcome of the fread is null. Here's the code - fname does exist, the path is correct, fil is non-zero, num is the number of sprites in the file (encoded into the header, little-endian), pak is an array of sprites, sprite is a typedef of width, height and bits, and new_sprite inits one for you.

```
FILE *fil;
uint8 *buffu;
uint8 read;
int32 x,num;
int32 w,h,c;

fil = fopen(fname, "rb");
if (!fil) return NULL;

num = fgetc(fil);
num += fgetc(fil)*256;
if (num > max) max = num;

for (x=0;x<max;x++) {
    // header
    w=fgetc(fil);
    w+=fgetc(fil)*256;
    h=fgetc(fil);
    h+=fgetc(fil)*256;
    fgetc(fil); // stuff we don't use
    fgetc(fil);
    fgetc(fil);
    fgetc(fil);
    // body
    buffu = (uint8*)malloc(w * h);
    read=fread(buffu,1,w*h,fil);
    pak->spr[x]=new_sprite(w,h);
    memcpy(pak->spr[x]->data, buffu, w*h);
    // done
    free(buffu);
}
```

I've stepped through this code line by line, and I can see that w and h are getting set up properly, and read=4096, which is the right number of bits. However, buffer is `""` after the fread, so of course memcpy does nothing useful and my pak is filled with empty sprites.

My apologies for what is surely a totally noob question, but I normally use Cocoa so this pure-C file handling is new to me. I looked all over for examples of fread, and they all look like the one here - which apparently works fine on Win32.

Comment: If you view a buffer as a string, be aware that the string representation will cut off if it sees a NUL byte. Better check the raw memory to be sure.

Comment: Oh boy, if that's it I feel really dumb. Using lldb, (gdb), what is the command for looking at the raw data?

Comment: No, it's definitely all nulls, I looped and printf'd the buffu.

Comment: Why do you declare `read` as `uint8`? And how is this variable able to hold 4096?

Comment: read is uint8 because I copy and pasted the line above it. What "this variable" do you mean, buffu? w and h are 64, 64x64 = 4096

Comment: _“and read=4096, which is the right number of bits”_. There's something wrong. `read` cannot hold the value 4096 and `fread` returns the number of items (here: bytes) read, not the bits.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc`. Further, if you are making an array of `uint8`, then you need to specify the `sizeof(uint8)` in your `malloc` call, to ensure that you are setting aside enough bytes. If you need an array of single bytes, use `unsigned char`, which is guaranteed to be one byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since fgetc seems to work, you could try this as a test

```
int each;
int byte;

//body
buffu = malloc(w * h);
for (each = 0; each < w*h; each++) {
    byte = fgetc(fil);
    if ( byte == EOF) {
        printf("End of file\n");
        break;
    }
    buffu[each] = (uint8)byte;
    printf ("byte: %d    each: %d\n", byte, each);
}
pak->spr[x]=new_sprite(w,h);
memcpy(pak->spr[x]->data, buffu, w*h);
// done
```

Comment: Perfect! I am getting data all along. Another debugger confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> However, buffer is "" after the fread, so of course memcpy does nothing useful

But that is not true at all. `memcpy()` is not a string function, it will copy the requested number of bytes. Every time. If that isn't "useful", then something else is wrong.

Your buffer, when treated as a string (which it is *not*, it's a bunch of binary data) will *look* like an empty string if the first byte happens to be 0. The remaining 4095 bytes can be whatever, to C's string printing functions it will look "empty".

Comment: Which describes the problem, but what is the solution to viewing it properly?